# multileven hierarchical header rows in gt

Tags: r, gt

I need a hierarchical table header like this

```
       level1             level2
------------------- -------------------
  group1   group2     group3   group4   
--------- --------- --------- ---------
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

It has 2 tab_spanners stacked on top of each other.
I could not find a way of doing it.
Can it be done?

Comment: `add_header_above()` in `kableExtra` will give you what you want if you're using `knitr`.  If not, we will need to know what packages you're using and file format you want.

Comment: I am using the package gt for tables

Comment: Thanks, but I am using `gt`, not `kable` and `kableExtre`